# Text inside form using WebBrowser.Document

Tags: c#, html, forms, webbrowser-control

first of all thank you for the help you provide to people like me. My problem is the following:

I am trying to write text in a webpage using the WebBrowser object of .NET. The problem is that this text is inside a form in the HTML structure. The code of the page is the following:

```
<form id="conv_weight" action="/es/" onsubmit="execute_weight(true); return false;">
<div>

Quiero convertir:
<div style="width: 152px">
<input type="text" name="amount" value="1" class="convert_from" onchange="execute_weight(true);" onkeyup="execute_weight(true);" style="width: 100%" />
</div>
```

And then continues with other items. I would like to change the value of the text "amount". How could I do that?

Comment: Which WebBrowser object? The Windows Forms version, or the WPF version, or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this if you are using WebBrowser Control.

```
 HtmlElementCollection allInputTags = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");

            if (allInputTags!=null && allInputTags.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (HtmlElement inp in allInputTags)
                {
                    if (inp.Name == "amount")
                    {
                        inp.SetAttribute("value", "EnterYourValue");
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
```